# Как подключить библиотеку Cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, lib

У меня есть папка с проектом и библиотекой. Не понимаю как к своему проекту Hello подключить библиотеку с помощью cmake.

```
├─ Hello
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├─ bib
├── lib
├────public
├────src
├──CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: если библиотека абстрактная - то никак.  Если какая то реальная, тогда есть решения.

Comment: @KoVadim библиотека реальная

Comment: я думаю Вы понимаете, что для начала нужно хотя бы назвать имя библиотеки или хотя бы описать ее. Да, для многих случаев подойдет find_package, для других нужно ручками прописать все.

Comment: ох. тогда Вам нужно почитать стандартную документацию. Там как раз это и описано https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20a%20Library.html